# Magnetic Moment MIT Bag Model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, commutator, magnetic-moment

I'm reading the book "Advances in Nuclear Physics vol 13" by J. W. Negele and Erich Vogt

In chapter 3, one wants to calculate the magnetic moment for a current loop.
In page 29 how does one go from equation 3.8 to 3.9:

equation 38:
$$\mu=\frac{N^2}{2}\sum_iQ_i\int_{bag}d\textbf{r} \ \textbf{r}^2[j_0(\omega r/R),-i\sigma_i\hat{r}j_1(\omega r/R)]
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \textbf{r}\times\sigma_i \\
\textbf{r}\times\sigma_i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 j_0(\omega r/R) \\
i\sigma_i\hat{r}j_1(\omega r/R) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

equation 39:

$$\mu=\mu_0\sum_i \sigma_iQ_i$$

Manipulating expression 38 I arrive at:

$$\sum_iQ_i\frac{N^2}{2}\int_0^R d\textbf{r} \ \textbf{r}^2\left(ij_0\left(\frac{\omega r}{R}\right)j_1\left(\frac{\omega r}{R}\right)[\textbf{r}\times\sigma_i,\sigma_i\hat{r}]\right)$$

Where $[\textbf{r}\times\sigma_i,\sigma_i\hat{r}])$ is the commutator.

How should I proceed? I know I should manage to isolate $\sigma_i$, but I don't know how to go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up expanding the commutator, using the levi-civita definition of the cross product. Arriving at the result:

$ [\textbf{r}\times \sigma_i, \sigma_i\hat{r}]=2i(\textbf{r}\sigma_i\hat{r}-\textbf{r}\sigma_i)$

From there I computed the integral and arrived at 3.9